# Codebuild is unable to find build directory

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, xcodebuild, aws-codepipeline, aws-codecommit

I am running my buildspec.yml where after npm run build command it should create the build directory in the root path, however, codebuild is unable to find the build directory.I have tried all possible ways from the resources, still I am unable to resolve **"no matching base directory path found for build"**

PS: I am using codecommit as the source, codebuild & codepipeline to run the deployment steps and S3 bucket to deploy the build directory.

My buildspec.yml

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 10
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Installing dependencies...
      - npm cache clean --force
      - npm install
      - npm --version
  
  build:
    commands:  
      - aws s3 rm s3://bucketname --recursive        
      
  post_build:
    commands:
           - pwd
           - cd src
           - npm run build
           - ls -la
           - aws s3 sync build s3://bucketname
       
artifacts:
  files:
        - "**/*"
```

Comment: You can use one S3 command to achieve your requirement `aws s3 sync ./build/ s3://bucketname/ --delete`

Without some more debug/logs or where the script fails I can only guess it is this line `cd src` causing your problems.

Comment: @GeorgeRushby yes, the `cd src` was causing the issue, I removed it and it worked like a charm, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to remove `cd src` from the post_build stage because my build and then it worked with pipeline, without any error.